# Are the Airport Operational Databases at major airports in the US available to the public?

Tags: airport, flight-data-monitoring

Are the Airport Operational Databases at major airports in the US available to the public? I am pretty sure it is not live but maybe released a month or so after.

## AODB

An AODB system is usually the core IT system to support the airport ground operations, it integrates with various systems from the heterogeneous IT landscape found at the airport, compiling data from airlines flights schedules, flight plan management, communication between airlines and airports to building management systems, live ground movements and many more systems.
It serves as platform for CDM (Collaborative Decision Making) for the various parties forming the airport community, from airport operators, airlines, groundhandling agents to ATC.

It handles seasonal and operational flights by providing both real-time and historical data, supports resource management for facilities and equipment, as well for staff, it is an information portal.

Comment: I've never heard of an airport making that much raw data publicly available. Many airports are run by public agencies, so you could try making a public records request for specific reports or documents under whatever local freedom of information law applies (if any), but that wouldn't be the same as the entire airport database. Some airports do make their [flight information display system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_display_system) FIDS publicly available online, showing roughly the same information as the displays in the terminals.

Comment: thanks, i figured they wouldn't release that much information